# JPA 2.0, Criteria API, many to many

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have two objects  - Car and Color. Each car can have set of colors. In database i have three tables Car, Car_color and Color.

I have sql-query  -

```
select  min(color.id) 

  from car
    join car_colors
      on car.id = car_color.car
    join color
      on car_color.color = color.id
  where car.id = 28;
```

How get data about object using Criteria API.

Truly yours, Nafanya.

Comment: Depends on the entities mappings. Can you give us (at least the relevant parts of) the entites?